# Replacing void spaces by cells on dynamically loaded HTML table using JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, html-table, cell

I have this table, I dynamically load it, and after that I add the according column headers for Well[#]. When I load the data I don't know from how many well's I'm getting data from. So I can't tell how big the table will be.

The question here is this, I have a table looking like so:

[image]

As you can see, I have void space filling the rows that are not 4 Wells long (pointed by red) and I'd like to fill those spaces with cells like the ones pointed by blue. I was analyzing the table using firebug, looking for some string that indicates that there's no cell at all, but there's no string at all to replace either.

I have the object `myTable()`, is there any method that allow me to do what I described above?

Comment: Can you post an example of your HTML in http://jsfiddle.net/?

Comment: Posting the structure of the table will be necessary to answer this with 100% accuracy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//cache the table element and find the number of columns
var $table       = $('table'),
    column_count = $table.find('tr').eq(1).children('td').length;

//iterate through each row
$table.find('tr').each(function () {

    //cache this row and it's children columns
    var $this = $(this),
        $tds  = $this.children('td');

    //check if the number of columns in this row is less than the number of columns in the header
    if ($tds.length < column_count) {

        //add the difference of the needed columns and the current columns to the row
        for (var i = 0, len = (column_count - $tds.length); i < len; i++) {
            $this.append('<td>&nbps;</td>');
        }
    }
});
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/AEjTZ/

Note that this looks at the second row in the table to see how many columns there are (I'm trying to target the green row in your screen-shot). You may have to change that to target the proper row (the green row in your screen-shot).

Comment: I don't think this will quite work because you assume that the first row contains the same number of td's as the problem row. However, he appears to be using colspans, so the numbers are in fact not equal.

Comment: @mrtsherman I stated that in my answer but it's not a big issue. You just have to change `.eq(1)` to whatever row the green row is in the question's screen-shot. Basically there **is** a row that has all the columns and it can be targeted. If it needs to be targeted dynamically you can iterate through the rows and find the largest number of columns in the table.

Comment: woops, I never looked past the code. Good solution then if he can easily identify his data rows. Which I think seems reasonable.

Comment: Thank you very much, this helped me a lot. I only had to add a cndition for the rows, so it'll skip the header and subheader (green one)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you are dynamically building this table, but when I have encountered this problem in the past, I am building it as a result from a SQL query which I'm looping over.  If that's how you're doing this, then the problem is likely that there are simply no records for those combinations of values (that particular well and genotype).  The solution that I've used is to alter the database query in such a way that will always return a row for each combination (well and genotype, in this case).  You can do that with an 'open' (also called cartesian) join between the base tables.  Then, left outer join back to the table that has the data you want to display there.  If you provide some SQL, I could assist with the construction of the query.

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem that is best solved during the generation of the table, instead of patching after the fact.  Is there a way for you to determine the max number of columns before you start writing out the tables?  If there is, you should do that.

If, for some reason, that is not possible, you can implement this:

```
var TRs = $('table tr');
var maxTD = Math.max.apply(Math,        // this is a generic solution, 
    $.map(TRs, function(tr, i) {        // for your case, you may just get the
        return $(tr).find('td').length; // length of the 2nd row
    }));

TRs.each(function(tr, i) {
    var addTD = maxTD - $(tr).find('td').length;
    $(tr).append(new Array(addTD + (1)).join('<td>&nbsp;</td>');
});
```